# How to change the background color of the QTableWidget's vertical header?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtstylesheets

I would like to change the colors of a `QTableWidget`. I am almost getting the result I like, but two areas in the vertical header remain white:

[image]

Before writing this post I actually managed to color also the upper left corner, but not the other area. Here is the stylesheet I am using:

```
QTableCornerButton::section {
    background-color: #8b8d8e;
}

QHeaderView::section {
    color: white;
    background-color: #747678;
    gridline-color: #747678;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer myself:

```
/*The top-left area is actually a button:*/
QTableCornerButton::section {
    background-color: #8b8d8e;
}
```

```
/*The lower part of the vertical header:*/
QHeaderView {
    background-color: #8b8d8e;
}
```

The original css I posted (QHeaderView::section) referred only to the header entries, not the header itself.

Answer (score 0):

`QTableCornerButton` is a private class of `QTableWidget`, you can enable and disable the button using the function `QTableView::setCornerButtonEnabled`, however, if you disable the button, that corner abstract button has a white background.

It is different from `QAbstractScrollArea::cornerWidget`, you can set another widget with `setCornerWidget`, but it won't override.

Even if the class is private, it can be acessed with the following code:

`QAbstractButton* qCorner =  this->findChild<QAbstractButton *>();`

Where `this` is a wrapper class for QTableWidget or use `yourTableObj` instead of this.

And then you can style:

```
qCorner->setStyleSheet("QTableCornerButton::section {"
                       "border: 0px;"
                       "background-color: " + QColor(Qt::black).name() +
                       ";}");
```

It is useful when you don't want to use stylesheet on the entire Table, be cause either you are using some Item delegates or using `QPalette`.